# Sharepoint 2016 and Visual Studio 2015 licence requirements

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio-2015, runtime

My company is moving forward with the early stages of migrating from Sharepoint 2010 to Sharepoint 2016.  We anticipate using Visual Studio to develop some of our business solutions.  I heard that in order for SharePoint and Visual Studio to work together, Visual Studio needs to be installed on the SharePoint server.

Does it require a unique software license or can it be Runtime?

Comment: do you have MSDN license?

Comment: Yes.  We have a MSDN License.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have the MSDN subscription, you can use it in your development machine without any issue. MSDN is for the development purpose but once you deploy it in Production you should have SharePoint 2016 license.

Our developer using the MSDN license for development.

Comment: I'm confident we will have the SharePoint License, I just wasn't sure if we needed an additional Visual Studio License on the server in addition to our workstations.

Comment: Do you want install Visual Studio on the production server?

Comment: I saw somewhere that it was required to be installed on the SharePoint server fully use Visual Studio within SharePoint.  I was just asking if it needs to be  a complete software package or if we had a runtime option.

Comment: I am not sure about this because we never have Visual studio in our production. we have tons of solutions...it is fine in Dev farm but production i am highly recommend to avoid it. SharePoint build in .net so no need any kind of runtime. Simply deploy your solution in production and you all set

Comment: Thank you so much for your time today.  Very informative.

Answer (score 0):

**SharePoint 2016 Migration**

New SharePoint version is always exciting with new features and better

> interfaces , but also equally stressful considering we have to move
> all our data from current version to the new version. Below are some
> basic information about migration to SharePoint 2016.
>
> **No direct migration path from 2007, 2010 to 2016:**
> If you are still
> running a SharePoint 2007 or 2010 version then things will be little
> more harder for you as 2007 or 2010 to 2016 native migration (database
> attach & upgrade) is not possibly directly. You have to first migrate
> to SharePoint 2013 and then from 2013 to 2016. See Upgrade from 2010
> to 2013 process. If you are in 2007 then you have a double hop process
> in front i.e. first migrate to 2010 , then to 2013 and finally you can
> go to 2016. Ways to avoid multiple migrations to reach to 2016: If you
> are running in MOSS 2007 or SharePoint 2010 , the only way to avoid
> multiple hops during migration is by using some third party migration
> tools like ShareGate, Metalogix , DocAve and tons of other tools out
> there in the market.This will make perfect sense if you do not want
> all data to be migrated but want to selectively migrate content from
> the existing 2007, 2010 or 2013 sites to SharePoint 2016. Migration
> from 2013 to 2016 : The native upgrade also require that your
> SharePoint 2013 database version is 15.0.4481.1005 (March 2013 Public
> update) or higher and if you have sites migrated from 2010, they
> should be visually upgraded to 2013 mode. Database attach and upgrade
> method should be used to migrate from 2013 to 2016.

```
 For Visual Studio Licensing
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/subscriptions/cc150618.aspx
```